# Retry Logic - retry whole class if one tests fails - selenium

Tags: selenium, testng, retry-logic

Following are the classes used to implement retry logic

TestRetry Class:

```
public class TestRetry implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    int counter=0;
    int retryLimit=2;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
         if (counter < retryLimit) {
              TestReporter.logStep("Retrying Test " +result.getName()+" for number of times: "+(counter+1));
              counter++;
              return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
```

RetryListener Class:

```
public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         IRetryAnalyzer retry = annotation.getRetryAnalyzer();

            if (retry == null) {

                annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(TestRetry.class);
    }

}}
```

SampleTest:

```
@Listeners(RetryListener.class)
public class SampleTest {

    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeSuite(ITestContext context) {
       for (ITestNGMethod method : context.getAllTestMethods()) {
              method.setRetryAnalyzer(new TestRetry());
       }
    }

    @Test(priority=0)
    public void firsttest() {
        System.out.println();
        TestReporter.assertEquals("Test", "Test", "pass");
    }
    @Test(priority=1, dependsOnMethods="firsttest")
    public void secondtest() {
        TestReporter.assertEquals("Test", "Test1", "fail");
    }
    @Test(priority=2,dependsOnMethods="secondtest")
    public void thirdtest() {
        TestReporter.assertEquals("Test", "Test", "pass");
    }
}
```

When I execute the above test, following is the output
firsttest gets executed and passes
secondtest depends on firsttest and gets executed, its failed - Retried 3 times and failed again
thirdtest skipped because it depends on secondtest.

Output achieved as expected.

Question:
Since the tests are dependent. If one of the tests fails, I want to execute the whole class from first. is there a way to do it?

Examples: 
If secondtest fails, I want to execute the whole class SampleTest again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way of achieving what you are asking for.

TestNG will only retry a failed test, but will not go up the execution ladder to find out all the upstream dependencies and try running them as well (Your ask is a very specific variant of this generic use case).

If you come to think of it, a dependent test is being executed only because its upstream dependencies (methods on which it depends on) have been executed successfully. So if there's a failure in the current test, why would one need to re-execute the already satisfied upstream dependencies? Its counter intuitive.

For what you have as a use-case, you should be merely building the entire logic within a `@Test` method, wherein you take care of handling the retries and also the invocation of the entire chain once again, if there were failures.

The below sample should clarify that

```java
public class SampleTest {

    @Test (retryAnalyzer = TestRetry.class)
    public void orchestrateTest() {
        firsttest();
        secondtest();
        thirdtest();
    }

    public void firsttest() {
        System.out.println();
        TestReporter.assertEquals("Test", "Test", "pass");
    }

    public void secondtest() {
        TestReporter.assertEquals("Test", "Test1", "fail");
    }

    public void thirdtest() {
        TestReporter.assertEquals("Test", "Test", "pass");
    }
}
```

TestNG does not support the use case that you are looking for in your question.

On a side note, you cannot wire in a `IAnnotationTransformer` listener via an `@Listeners` annotation (this is explicitly called out in the javadocs of this interface). It can only be wired in via the `<listeners>` tag in your suite xml (or) by referring to it in the `META-INF\services\org.testng.ITestNGListener` file (its called the [Service Provider Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) approach in Java)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, It's really helpful.

Comment: @user9586244 - please accept my answer if it helped